# Using interact in ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, interactive, ipywidgets

Consider the function below:

```py
def f(x,y):
   return x * y
```

Using interact I could write the following:

```py
interact(f, x = fixed(2), y = (1,20))
```

and this would fix x at 2 and allow me to vary y between 1 and 20.

But, what if I wanted the interact part to be called automatically when I ran the function?
Hi,
So if I were to write:

```py
f(2)
```

it would automatically make x equal to 2 and then allow the user to vary the y value from 1 to 20.

How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Once the interact has run, you want to call the function so that the value of x is 2 and you can change y? Isn't the value of x fixed to begin with

Comment: I basically just want it so I can write f(2) and x will be fixed at 2 but you can vary y.

Comment: Isn't `interact(f, x = fixed(2), y = (1,20))` already fixing x at the value 2? Do you want to change that value after running interact?